# The code only works for some android versions

Tags: android

I wanted to save a picture from drawable. The application works, but only for android versions below API 22. In newer versions, the image is not saved in gallery.

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Bitmap anImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tapeta1, null);
        anImage = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
    }

    public void addImageToGallery(View view) {
        int e = view.getId();

        switch (e) {
            case R.id.button:
                saveImageToExternalStorage(anImage);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved successfully, Check gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void saveImageToExternalStorage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images_1");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    }
                });

    }

}
```

Comment: Very sorry should be "below API 23"

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have granted the storage permission to your app from

> Settings -> Apps -> Your App Name ->Permissions

If this solution fixes your issue then please read - https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

Before you anthing else on oncreate method call    requestpermissions by passing write external storage permission . This will show user to grant permission . You can override onpermissionsresult in the activity to see the result of permissions if granted you can go ahead with saving  the file . If you dont want all that then save in internal storage  . getfilesdir method will get you the path to app's internal directory and will not need runtime permissions .

Answer (score 0):

You need to request [RunTime permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) from app.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }
```